# PostgreSQL nested CTE and UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, common-table-expression

I'm trying to learn SQL, using PostgreSQL 9.1.3.  I would like to understand some behavior that strikes me as inconsistent.  To wit:

This works:

```
WITH innermost AS (SELECT 2)
SELECT * FROM innermost
UNION SELECT 3;
```

I get this:

```
 ?column? 
----------
        2
        3
```

This works:

```
WITH outmost AS (
        (WITH innermost AS (SELECT 2)
         SELECT * FROM innermost)
)                                
SELECT * FROM outmost;
```

Result:

```
?column? 
----------
        2
```

This also works:

```
WITH outmost AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION (WITH innermost AS (SELECT 2)
         SELECT * FROM innermost)
)
SELECT * FROM outmost;
```

I get this:

```
 ?column? 
----------
        1
        2
```

But this does **not** work:

```
WITH outmost AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION (WITH innermost as (SELECT 2)
         SELECT * FROM innermost
         UNION SELECT 3)
)
SELECT * FROM outmost;
```

Result:

```
ERROR:  relation "innermost" does not exist
LINE 4:          SELECT * FROM innermost
```

To my way of thinking, either the last one should succeed or one of the other ones should fail.  I don't see the pattern.  Is there some general rule that would enable me to predict what combinations of nested CTEs and UNIONs will or will not work?

Comment: Though your final query looks awkward, it should be Ok, IMHO. It could be a precedence/associativity error in the parser. There are some semantic restrictions (No nested recursive CTEs, IIRC); maybe the parser is too picky, or too trigger-happy. Personally, I use a lot of nested CTEs (up to 4 levels deep), but I rarely use UNION, except for in the recursive CTEs.

Comment: @AdamMackler you should put that in as the answer to your own question

Comment: Tom Lane acknowledging you found a bug, is  something like an official approval that you asked a very good question. Please post what you got from the list as answer and be sure to add a link to the thread.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The mystery is solved: the behavior I was observing is a known bug.  I sent the same original post to a PostgreSQL-specific list and got this answer:

> This is a bug :-(.  The parse analysis code seems to think that WITH
>   can only be attached to the top level or a leaf-level SELECT within a
>   set operation tree; but the grammar follows the SQL standard which
>   says no such thing.  The WITH gets accepted, and attached to the
>   intermediate-level UNION which is where syntactically it should go,
>   and then it's entirely ignored during parse analysis.  Will see about
>   fixing it.
>
> ```
>       regards, tom lane
> ```

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2012-07/msg00113.php

Comment: Seems like this has been fixed in 9.2 beta3. I quote the newsletter: `* Fix WITH issue with set operations (UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT)`.

Comment: I just installed 9.2beta3 and yes, the nonworking command in my original post does now work as expected.  Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for tracking this down! Your question deserves more upvotes. :)  BTW, it's encouraged to accept your own (correct) answer in such a case.